# Is it possible to build static(.a) lib for iOS from visual studio 2013?

Tags: ios, c, visual-studio, static-libraries

I have c code and i have not used any OS related calls. I had build static lib for windows using visual studio 2013. Now I want to build static lib for an iOS.

Is there any way do it without using Mac OS (XCode) ?

If not then what are those technical reasons (only because of compiler)? Because i read Static libraries are simply a collection of ordinary object files.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: there could be a way to use gcc to compile your static lib and would be able to be included in an iOS project, im not sure though

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it very much... you are going to have to upgrade to a Mac.

By the way, you don't need to use the XCode integrated environment on the Mac, the compilation toolchain can be controlled from the command line, with `make` and other tools.  So you could just get a Mac, install XCode there and mount a shared Windows file system and use `putty` to launch the tools from Windows via ssh.

Comment: It was a hint to the 2009 Apple campaign *Make the ultimate upgrade. To Mac*.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to use a MAC for that.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is possible, for example by getting a version of gcc able to cross-compile to ARM architecture with the proper file format/ABI and setting up Visual Studio to use it for compilation. Not sure it would be worth it unless you just need to compile some library for several platforms and want to do it from one place.

There seem to be even [tools for compiling whole applications for iOS on Windows](http://www.pmbaty.com/iosbuildenv/), but having never used them cannot say how usable it would be.

So all in all, it is possible to compile the library, but probably not the simplest thing to do.